# Java обработать строку

Tags: java

Думаю, будет проще сразу с примера.

Есть строка. Допустим - `"A\rB"`. Она содержит 3 `ASCII` символа - `65 13 66` - их коды (в чем можно убедиться, выполнив это):

```
String s = "A\rB";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    System.out.print((int)s.charAt(i) + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Но вывод сего будет лишь `B`, в чем тоже можно убедиться, выполнив это:

```
System.out.println(s);
```

Понятное дело, `carriage return` переводит курсор в самое начало строки, после чего символ `B` затирает символ `A`.

Вопрос следующий: могу ли я (встроенными средствами, или какой-то авторитетной либой) взять, да и "почистить" строку такого вида?

Чтобы от строки `"A\rB"` осталось лишь `"B"`? Смысл от этого не изменится, а данных по сети слать придется меньше. Спасибо.

Comment: Почему бы не попробовать разбить строку с помощью `split()`, используя как разделитель перевод каретки? Этот способ сработает к тому-же даст вам возможность адекватно отработать данные перед отправкой, если например перевод каретки будет не один а несколько.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов и что это мне даст? Несколько строк?) От одной проблемы к нескольким, как обычно?)

Comment: Ну почему-же? Получая массив из строк до разделителя и после, можно абстрактно посылать куда-то данные, или я не правильно понял задачу?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов видимо, совсем уж неправильно)